# Заменить символ в строке при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка:

```
hello worldhello worldhello worldhello world
```

Надо заменить одиночные `l` на `*`, чтобы получилось:

```
hello wor*dhello wor*dhello wor*dhello wor*d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, можно использовать такое регулярное выражение для поиска одиночных букв l

```
(?<!l)l(?!l)
```

Отрицательное "заглядывание назад" за буквой l, потом собственно буква l, потом отрицательное "заглядывание вперёд" за буквой l.

Comment: А прокомментируйте пожалуйста, чтобы не просто сдирать)) Хотя, наверно я так понятно. Первая не 'l', потом 'l'  и следующая не 'l'. Правильно?

Comment: Немного расширил свой комментарий для понятности. Да, всё так :)

Comment: Вообще, можно и на других принципах сделать аналогичное выражение, просто первое что в голову пришло.